# Switch Case Cast Pattern Matching

Tags: swift

```
let number: Any = 10

switch number {
    case 10 as Int:
       print ("10")
    default:
       break
}
```

I am just wondering what steps the compiler take to resolve the value of constant **number**? Does the compiler cast **number** to Int first and then compare it to the literal **10**? Or does it compare the **number** to **10** and then cast afterward?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is basically the same as the following:

```
let x: Int = 10
let number: Any = x

if let y = number as? Int, y == 10 {
   print("10")
}
```

The compiler checks whether the values has correct type (`Int` in this case), then cast it and then compares it to the given value (`10`).

There is no other way how this could go since you cannot really compare values of different types.

Comment: That is what I initially thought how it worked. But then I thought about it. It does not make sense to me.

let change the code to the following:

let number: Any = 10.0

switch number {
    case 10 as Double:
       print ("10.0")
    default:
       break
}

Comment: @kenryuakuma That won't pass because `number` is of type `Int`. What is the problem?

Comment: Then according to the code you listed it would become like this

let number: Any = 10.0

if let x = number as? Double, number == 10 {
   print ("10.0")
}

But since we cannot compare different type. Because now we are comparing double to int since number is cast to be type double but the literal 10 is Int. It should fail to compile. But as a matter of fact, it works and the code compile fine. This is pretty confusing or one of the most horrible pattern matching.

Comment: @kenryuakuma I had a typo in my original code which is fixed now. We never compare `Double` to `Int`. We are trying to cast `Any` to `Double` and if that succeeds, we then compare `Double` with `Double`. Make sure you understand that `10` is a literal and has no type on its own. The type is inferred from context  (or `Int` when it cannot be inferred).

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense. That has really cleared up the whole confusing pattern matching thing. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make some instrumented data types that hook into the various functions that are called, and print details about them. That will help you get some insight into the order of things:

```
struct InstrumentedInt: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, Equatable {
    let value: Int

    init(integerLiteral: Int) {
        print("Initializing InstrumentedInt from \(integerLiteral)")
        self.value = integerLiteral
    }

    static func == (lhs: InstrumentedInt, rhs: InstrumentedInt) -> Bool {
        print("checking \(lhs) == \(rhs)")
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}

struct InstrumentedDouble: ExpressibleByFloatLiteral, Equatable {
    let value: Double

    init(integerLiteral: Int) {
        print("Initializing InstrumentedInt from \(integerLiteral)")
        self.value = Double(integerLiteral)
    }

    init(floatLiteral: Double) {
        print("Initializing InstrumentedInt from \(floatLiteral)")
        self.value = floatLiteral
    }

    static func == (lhs: InstrumentedDouble, rhs: InstrumentedDouble) -> Bool {
        print("checking \(lhs) == \(rhs)")
        return lhs.value == rhs.value
    }
}

func instrumentedValueProducer(value: Any) -> Any {
    print("Producing value \(value)")
    return value
}

let instrumentedInt: InstrumentedInt = 10
let instrumentedDouble: InstrumentedDouble = 20.0

switch instrumentedValueProducer(value: instrumentedDouble) {
    case 10 as InstrumentedInt: print("10 as InstrumentedInt")
    case 20.0 as InstrumentedDouble: print("20 as InstrumnetedDouble")
    default: print("default")
}
```

> Initializing InstrumentedInt from 10
>
> Initializing InstrumentedInt from 20.0
>
> Producing value InstrumentedDouble(value: 20.0)
>
> Initializing InstrumentedInt from 20.0
>
> checking InstrumentedDouble(value: 20.0) == InstrumentedDouble(value: 20.0)
>
> 20 as InstrumentedDouble

Surprisingly, even though `20` is the second case, the compiler doesn't call the initializer `InstrumentedInt.init(integerLiteral: 10)` for use in comparison. I guess the optimizing is able to be smart and create a look up table that skips the value generation entirely, somehow.

Comment: `InstrumentedInt.init(integerLiteral: 10)` isn't called in the switch because the conditional cast to `InstrumentedInt` fails before the literal has a chance to be constructed. Admittedly, the pattern matching syntax for type casting is horrible. `10 as InstrumentedInt` as an *expression* is a coercion of `10` to `InstrumentedInt`. However, `10 as InstrumentedInt` as a *pattern* is a conditional cast of the value being matched to `InstrumentedInt` followed by a comparison to the literal `10` coerced to `InstrumentedInt`.

Comment: @Hamish That's what I thought, but I couldn't figure out why `(10 as InstrumentedInt) as Any` wasn't causing an initialization and call to `==`

Comment: Because that’s a conditional cast pattern within a conditional cast pattern :) The value to match is first cast to `Any`, and then conditionally cast to `InstrumentedInt`.

Comment: @Hamish Oh, interesting. Didn't expect that.